# Simple product - show a dropdown of attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I already have 900 products on a site that are simple products with attributes. On most of the products there is an attribute called 'grade' which some have different option. All attributes are already set in the products.
eg. product 1 - has grade attributes '1 '2' and '3'
Product 2 - has '2' and '3'

I want to display a dropdown for each product on the archive page that will let the user choose their grade before they add to cart. When this has been selected they can click add to cart button. Nothing needs to change all that needs to happen is that the grade will show in the basket and cart and order forms etc.

It is not an option to turn all products into variable products as everything is already set up. We don't need anything on the product to change. It is just so the user can select their grade option.

I am using a Child Theme and Woocommerce to achieve this.

I asked Chat GPT to help but it's not really understanding the issue.

I got this code which did output all of the grade options but the issue with the below was we couldn't add the selected to the basket.

```
    $grade = $product->get_attribute('pa_grade');

    if (!empty($grade)) {
        echo '<label for="product_grade">Grade:</label>';
        echo '<select name="product_grade" id="product_grade">';
        echo '<option value="">Select</option>';

        // Split the attribute values by comma and trim each value
        $grade_values = array_map('trim', explode(',', $grade));

        // Loop through the grade values and create an option for each
        foreach ($grade_values as $grade_value) {
            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($grade_value) . '">' . esc_html($grade_value) . '</option>';
        }

        echo '</select>';
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Simple product Ajax add to cart feature doesn't accept any additional custom data…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec , I understand that, as I was wondering if there is a way to output this custom dropdown on the cart, basket and woocom emails

Comment: You didn't provide any information needed to help you answer your question. You show us how you render a select on the screen, but you are asking how to make that data get into your backend and stored in you cart information. You need to provide information on how your whole backend works, if you are using an custom or open-source eCommerce solution and exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question 'I am using a Child Theme and Woocommerce to achieve this.'. Is there anything else that people would need to know?

Comment: There is no interest in doing that, as you will not get the selected value…

Comment: _"It is not an option to turn all products into variable products as everything is already set up."_ - even if you implement a "workaround" now, instead of setting things up properly - then the _next_ change or feature request might very likely still bite you in that regard. What about stuff like automatic stock keeping, do you not need that at all? Because that's also not going to work out-of-the-box, when you only get _one_ stock count, for what are actually two or three _different_ products.

Comment: you will need to make custom ajax add to cart process with custom field.

Comment: If you make the products variable, and make each grade a variation, there are out of the box solutions on stackexchange, if this is [what you want to achieve?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOixz.gif) [link to code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/327002/223934). Each grade is a variant to the parent product, even if the price is the same for all variations. When it's a variable product, each variation gets a unique id WooCommerce can refer to. It is also viable if you want to integrate with stock management or other EDI systems. I just think you have to reverse/rethink your setup